# Cannot increase max file size upload above 2gb

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, local

Im using Local By Flywheel and All in one migration, Im trying to copy over my live site to a local for development, Ive exported the file and its 4gb (the live site), Trying to upload it but have a max file size limit.

1. I have installed an old version of the plugin and increased the limit on the plugin itself (which i think has worked)
2. I added this to my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 4GB
memory_limit = 25600M
post_max_size = 4GB
```

When i change those values, The max size in wordpress will match them (eg if i set the max to 500M then the file limit will change to 500MB which shows that it is working in some way) but it doesnt seem to allow me to go over 2GB. Does anyone have any ideas about what this could be?

*Also i have used

```
 $size = wp_max_upload_size();
```

to check the max file size and it shows that the max is 2gb. I have done this on multiple themes too, All print the same result.

Comment: Just print <?php phpinfo(); and do ctrl+F search for memory_limit there. There will be 2 columns. 1. local value. 2. master value.  The one you are setting is a local value. And if you set its value bigger than master value, it will simply be ignored by your hosting. Same with post_max_size parameter there.

Comment: I have printed that and recieve the value i set above (25600M)

Comment: What about master value?

Comment: Where are those set?

Comment: When you write phpinfo(); you can clearly see both values. left one is the one you set, right one is whether master value allows that big value. see screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IzSFU7H-OSwQETrHO9ZmnkeBxqcHCmj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: They are the same, Both 25600M

Comment: Very good. Then the problem is related to different parameter. Have you debugged the problem? What does your error log say?  Turn wp_debug to true to see what error you are getting each time.

Comment: A different parameter? Im running wp_debug and dont get any errors

Comment: If you don't face any error, then how do you know that doesn't work?

Comment: ...Because i cant upload a file size more than 2gb and it tells me that the max size is 2gb.

Comment: Can you tell me where and how it "tells" you that? Can you paste there exact error message from your webpage or error.log file?

Comment: The error is on the wordpress site, When I upload a file it says "maximum 2gb"

Comment: There is no any WordPress/PHP error message which can just tell "maximum 2gb". It will be better if you add some screenshots from the screen where you catched the error

Comment: Dude... The max file size said 2gb. This is actually quite common you can google it if you want. I appreciate the help but I gave up on this way and will find another. Thanks

Comment: "A problem well stated is a problem half solved" - Charles Kettering. I know at least 5 possible reasons of your problem (32bit vs 64bit, php conf problem, webserver's hard limitation etc.) and each one has absolutely different solution.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for trying anyway dude.